# How to get rid of small corners which appear during the transition?

Tags: css

Please see the example. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ojLxdw6v/

Button and button container both have border-radius. Also button container has `overflow: hidden`. 
But somehow corners are visible while transition.

I thought to add `overflow: hidden` to Button. 
But it's no luck also. Transparent semicircles appear between container border and link background on the right and left side.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow:hidden` to the `.btn` and change the background color after the pseudo-elements have moved.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ojLxdw6v/9/)

```
.btn{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 9px 34px 9px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 6px solid #fed37f;
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: background 0 ease 500ms;
}

.btn:hover {
    background:#fed37f;
}
```